# 'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments -- why? :/

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try serialize my list to string and error "'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

```
[Serializable]
class ComponentSerialization 
{

    public string komponent;

    /**
    * Konstruktor
    */
    public ComponentSerialization(string v) {
        ustawKomponent(v);
    }

        public void ustawKomponent(string v) {   
        this.komponent = v;

    }


        public string pobierzKomponent() {
        string kom = new string();
        kom = this.komponent;
        return kom;
    }

}
```

why not working? :/

Comment: Well, why is pretty evident: `string` does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments, thats why. `new string()` would basically create an empty string, just use `""` or `String.Empty`.

Comment: There should be a "How to read & understand Stacktraces" ...

Answer (score 4):

`string` doesn't have default constructor ([String Class - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) - see `Constructors` section - there is no constructor without parameters) so, you get this error - you try to call constructor that doesn't exists in `String` class.

Default constructor in `String` class is not needed. Strings are `immutable`. It means that after creation some string when you try to change it actually you don't change created string - you create new one.

In your case you don't need constructor - you don't create objects, you simply assign references.

Change this:

```
string kom = new string();
kom = this.komponent;
```

to this:

```
string kom = this.komponent;
```

Also, you can refactor your code a little more. These lines:

```
string kom = new string();
kom = this.komponent;
return kom;
```

can be replaced by only one:

```
return this.komponent;
```

Comment: "*So, if it were default constructor you would create "something empty" that can't be changed*". And? An empty string is still useful in many scenarios. That is not the real reason why `string()` does not exist. It doesn't exist simply due to efficiency through reusability: the literal `""` will be interned and `string.Empty` is one single instance that can be used infinite times. Its the same principle as `ImmutableStack<T>.Empty`. You only need one empty stack in an immutable world.

Comment: @InBetween, thanks, I edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Because `string` is **immutable**. That means you never change the content of a `string` instance.

In these two lines

```
string kom = new string();
kom = this.komponent;
```

the initialisation in the first line is useless. The new instance (if it would be created) would be thrown immediatly because you assing `this.komponent` in the next line. So simply change it to

```
string kom = this.komponent;
```

So there is *no use for a parameterless constructor*. If you need an empty string, use `string.Empty` instead.

Comment: The reason I mention immutability is to answer the question _why_ no parameterless constructor was provided by the designers. There is no useful scenario for it since you won't change the content of that instance, and an empty string is already "allocated" and stored in `string.Empty`.

Comment: yeah, true, deleted comment. Took me a while to understand you were actually answering "why there is no parameterless constructor", not "why doesn't my code compile" which is what I think the OP is really asking. Your answer is leaps and bounds ahead of the OPs problems I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
string kom = new string();
kom = this.komponent;
```

with

```
string kom = this.komponent;
```

There is no constructor for `string` class so you run into this error

Answer (score 0):

Since string are immutable a constructor without parameters would not maky any sense. Instead if you want to declare a string without any value set it to null.
Also in your case the function pobierzKomponent is unneccessary long. Just do something like this

```
public string pobierzKomponent()
{
        return this.komponent
}
```

or even better since that string is public declare it as property `public string Komponent{get;set;}` and access it directly without any getter function